# Embed unknown file formats

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash-cs4

Using the Embed tag, we can embed in the swf file not only swf's or jpg's etc, but also unsupported file formats like:

`Embed[(source="mzip.zip", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]`

public static MyZip:Class;

When i instantiate such a class, what type of object do i get? Is it possible to get a ByteArray from this class?

When i do this:
`package {
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;`

```
public final class Resource {       
    [Embed(source="p2.zip", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
    public static const MyZip:Class;

    public static function getByteArrayFromZip():ByteArray {
        var zip:ByteArray = new MyZip as ByteArray;
        return zip;
    }
}
```

}

and

`public class Main extends Sprite {

        private var ship:Bitmap;
        private var lib:FZipLibrary;`

```
    public function Main() {            
        lib = new FZipLibrary();    
        lib.formatAsBitmapData(".jpg");       
        lib.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,onCompleteHandler);

        var fzip:FZip = new FZip();
        fzip.loadBytes(Resource.getByteArrayFromZip());
        lib.addZip(fzip);
    }

   private function onCompleteHandler(evt:Event) {
        var image:BitmapData = lib.getBitmapData("assets/graphics/scratchers/myimg.jpg");
        trace("Size: " + image.width + "x" + image.height); 
        var sa0img0:Bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
        addChild(sa0img0);
   }
}
```

}

The i get the following error:
`TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Main/onCompleteHandler()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at deng.fzip::FZipLibrary/processNext()
    at deng.fzip::FZipLibrary/loaderCompleteHandler()`

Comment: If you do not use the "as" cast (X as ByteArray) but a normal explicit cast instead you will get an error right away. So instead of "X as ByteArray" you should write "ByteArray(X)". It will not convert the result to null if the cast fails.

Comment: Besides, your error happens in onCompleteHandler, so what is null there? Maybe step through it with a debugger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just instantiate MyZip and cast as a ByteArray.

```
Embed[(source="mzip.zip", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
public static var MyZip:Class;

var zip:ByteArray = new MyZip() as ByteArray;
```

Comment: can you check my update on main question, i did as you said but still get an error.

Comment: Have you checked the value of zip?  Is it a ByteArray?  If so, then the question is answered and it looks like you have a different problem.  It looks like the problem is with FZip.  Try tracing out the image variable in the onCompleteHandler method to see if that is your null.  But you should really ask another question for this.

Comment: Ok i found the problem i was giving a wrong path to find the image inside the zip!!I corrected the path, used the code as you told and now works, thanks!